# CSS Определить отсутствие tag элемента в DOM

Tags: html, css, css3

Возможно ли средствами CSS узнать что в DOM дереве нет какого-то элемента? Вот как пример (не рабочий)

```css
body:not(h1):after {
    content: 'You forgot h1';
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
```

То есть, по сути, хочется видеть что забыли добавить h1, если его нету в DOM.

PS Я слышал про `:has()` но пока он не работает

Comment: А если H1 вложен ещё в какой-то блок, тогда как?

Comment: Не знаю. в будущем это по идеи должно так работать  `body:not(:has(h1)):after {content: 'You forgot h1'; }` но пока `:has()` не работает, возможно есть другой костыльный способ проверить на отсутсвие ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это и невозможно в актуальном стандарте CSS, и за рамками назначения стилей (которое заключается именно в стилизации элементов).

Здесь целью (желаемым результатом выполнения) является вывод текста отсутствующего в документе изначально, с императивной логикой условия (если..то) - именно поэтому, данная задача выходит за границы адекватного применения стилей.
То есть, даже будь в CSS возможность решения таких задач - возможности должны использоваться *разумно*, не только лишь из-за их наличия.

Задачи такого рода, подразумевающие императивное программирование, `если {вычисляемое условие} то {выполнить операции с контентом документа}` - следует решать средствами JS, в соответствии с ролью каждой технологии: статическому контенту следует находиться в разметке; за динамический контент и императивную логику отвечают скрипты; за внешний вид элементов отвечают стили. Следование этой простой организации имеет множество преимуществ, а ее нарушение - может приводить к множеству проблем.
Рекомендую сделать выбор в пользу преимуществ.

---

*// Несмотря на то что CSS в ряде случаев позволяет успешно избежать использования скриптов (в задачах где естественным образом предполагается их использование) - такое избежание все же является костылем/хаком по самой сути, и не стоит забывать об этом: применяя костыли только при **реальной** необходимости (которая встречается все реже, благодаря постепенному развитию и стандартизации веб-технологий, а также все новым оптимизациям браузеров). Чрезмерное увлечение костылями может негативно сказаться и на UX, и на личном прогрессе веб-разработчика*.

Comment: объяснение интересное, спасибо. По сути, как написал выше `body:not(:has(h1)):after {content: 'You forgot h1'; }` решит вопрос в будущем, возможно всё таки есть что-то уже сейчас?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 – да. Называется JavaScript.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, есть, средствами JS это реализуется в 2-3 строки кода: `if (!document.querySelector('h1')) document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="danger">You forgot h1</div>');` _//переносы строк в комментариях не позволены, увы_

Answer (score 0):

В CSS есть псевдокласс `:empty`. Таким образом, вы можете обернуть `h1` в `div`, на котором проверите, нет ли в нём вложенных элементов:

```css
.box {
  background: lime;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.box:empty:after {
    content: 'You forgot h1';
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"><h1></h1></div>
```

Comment: `:empty` не подходит, поскольку интересно узнать отсутствие конкретного тега, Ваш пример не будет работать если первое условие, допустим будет таким `<div class="box"><p></p></div>`

Comment: @BlackStar1991 я про это и написал, что в элементе не должно быть вложенных элементов.